# where is the server.js file on node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm reading a book about integrating nodejs with backbonejs and there is this part of the book
(its supposed to be the basics)

(...)

npm install express

Finally, just copy the following code into server.js. As you can see from the code, it provides some simple
endpoints served from localhost:8080/ books.

```
/**
* A simple API hosted under 127.0.0.1:8080/books
*/
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
varbookId = 100;

functionfindBook(id){
for(vari =0; i<books.length; i++){
if(books[i].id === id){
return books[i];
}
}
return null;

}
```

(...)

I already installed node and expressjs, where is that server.js file or where did I put it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the express.js documentation](http://expressjs.com/guide.html):

> Now to create the application itself! **Create a file named app.js or server.js**, whichever you prefer, require express and then create a new application with express():

Answer (score 6):

You need to create that file yourself and place it inside the root folder of your project